# I need a guide on how to save my app state

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a guide on how to save my app state just as when a user increase the font size,  I want to save that so the same size will be applied to the text of another page the user navigate to.

Comment: Here is how to pass data from one screen to another: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways of doing that. One way is if you want not only to hold the font size value across pages but across sessions too, I would recommend using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package. You can then retrieve the font size value every time the user starts a new session and also wrap the root of the app with a ChangeNotifier that rebuilds itself every time the user changes the font size.

You can them share that value across your app with the state management technique you choose. Or use to set the `TextStyle` property in the `MaterialApp(theme: )` and access it like `TextStyle(fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize);`